# Crontab - How to make script run every 15 minutes from 12:00 PM to 03:00 AM

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have tried so many things. 
For example, I first tried the most logic by me

```
*/15 12-3 * * * script.sh
```

but the crontab doesn't allow me to save it like that so I tried

```
*/15 12-0,0-3 * * * script.sh
```

and once again the crontab doesn't allow me to save it. Now I lose one hour because it is running like this

```
*/15 12-23,0-3 * * * script.sh
```

Can you please help me with this problem. I am sure there is a way I just cannot find it.

Comment: Have a look at [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_0-3,12-23_*_*_*)

Comment: @jww The OP does not have problem with a script, but the syntax of crontab, and he has shown what he has attempted. There are not really many duplicates that explains that cron cannot parse `12-3` in a sensible manner.

Comment: @nos - As I understand the site's rules, how to configure crontab is off-topic at Stack Overflow. OP probbably sould visit [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
*/15 0-3,12-23 * * * script.sh
```

should do the trick. Note that ranges are inclusive, so the script will execute for all hours, without skipping any.

Comment: What do you mean by this "the script will execute for all hours", do you mean that the script will execute every single hour or every hour between 12:00 PM and 03:00 AM?

Comment: It is like having a line `*/15 23 * * * script.sh`, running at `23:00`, `23:15`, `23:30`, `23:45`, without missing the hour 23:00 - 24:00.

Comment: Yes, precisely what Walter said.